# tomcat as windows service - increase max java heap memory

Tags: java, windows-services, tomcat5.5, heap-memory

i have tomcat5.5 installed as a windows service, and I need to change the java memory pool. however, when i enter any amount more than 1348 mb, the service doesn't start.
IS there any way to get around this? Would it help if I installed it the non-windows-service way?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A windows application is limited to 2Gb of memory for the application, so as well as 1348Mb you have specified there are teh other memory pools and of course the JVM it's self.

There is a windows setting you can specify at boot time to allow an application to use 3Gb, but sun's JVM does not play ball with it.  JRockit does though

Alternately would it be possible to cluster tomcat and distribute the work load?